# Trouble with identifying a value in a drop down (Selenium Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium (Python) to select a value from a drop down list, but I'm having some problems.

When I use Selenium IDE, it identifies the drop down as a button, as follows :

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")
```

I then tried to select a value from the list by using:

```
    Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).select_by_visible_text("Africa/Juba")
```

That doesn't work because it says "Select only works on  elements, not on buttons.

When I inspect the element, I can't see anything useful that I can use to identify the drop down (this is just some of it):

```
<select selectpicker="" ng-options="timezone for timezone in model.timezones" ng-model="newAccount.timeZoneId" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid bs-select-hidden" data-live-search="true">  <option value="0" label="Africa/Abidjan">Africa/Abidjan</option><option value="1" label="Africa/Accra">Africa/Accra</option>  <option value="2" label="Africa/Addis_Ababa">Africa/Addis_Ababa</option>  <option value="3</option></select>
```

Is there another way that I can select a value from the drop down list?

Answer (score 2):

The element you are getting with your `Xpath` is a `button`. You cannot use `Select` with buttons. You want to get the `select` element.
Try this:

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@ng-model='newAccount.timeZoneId']")).select_by_visible_text("Africa/Juba")
```

**Edit**
The problem you are having makes sense. In the `HTML` you shared there is no `option` element containing the text `Africa/Juba`. If you would change `Africa/Juba` to `Africa/Algiers` it should work without problem.
In the comments you mentioned this this element: `<span class="text">Africa/Juba</span>`. This is missing from your `HTML` example. However a `span` inside a `select` should not work. You can use the `Select` class when dealing with `options`.

Comment: I tried to run that, but I got an error saying:

        "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"           Even though the drop down has expanded and the option is visible on the screen

Comment: @Chris It's hard to tell what the problem is. Is the site public so I can try it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's still being developed. Would it help if I asked for the drop down to have an id added to it, to make it easier for Selenium to identify? It seems to be having a problem recognizing the drop down when it uses that XPath

Comment: I doubt it can't find the drop down. I think it can't find the `Africa/Juba` element. You could try splitting this in 2 actions, finding the `select` first and selecting the `Africa/Juba` afterwards so you can see which of the two causes problems.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with selecting "Africa/Juba", the first action worked fine when I split them up.
The identifier for it is : <span class="text">Africa/Juba</span>

Comment: I had a look at the edit and tried to make changes based on that, but I'm still having problems.
I inspected the element again and noticed that there was a different class for the "option" elements (please excuse my references, I'm not too familiar with HTML). I right clicked on the class where all the "option elements" are stored under and copied the XPath for that. I tried the following (which still gives me an element not visible exception): 

Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="widget-5"]/div/fieldset[1]/div/div[3]/div/select""")).select_by_visible_text("Africa/Juba")

Comment: Using Selenium IDE, I was able to see the XPath of the specific drop down item that it clicked on. It's not ideal because I would need to identify the XPath of any drop down value I want to use, but this does work:

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='widget-5']/div/fieldset/div/div[3]/div/div/div/ul/li[27]/a/span").click()

Comment: @Chris Could you edit the `HTML` in your answer with the actual `HTML` you are working with. Right now you're having an example which is different than what you are using and I have no clue what your situation is.